# pandas profiling while importing Profile_Report

Tags: python, pandas

I installed pandas profiling using code

```
import sys
!{sys.executable} -m pip install -U pandas-profiling[notebook]
!jupyter nbextension enable --py widgetsnbextension
```

and it run successfully

But when i try to import from pandas_profiling import ProfileReport
it will show error

> ImportError: cannot import name 'to_html' from
> 'pandas_profiling.report'
> (C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas_profiling\report_*init*_.py)

[about error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BL1j7.png)